# Why can't I evaluate this OCaml line with tuareg mode's C-c C-e command?

Tags: ocaml, tuareg

Background: I'm using Emacs 23.3, OCaml 3.12.0 and tuareg 1.45.7.

I'm looking at the [Hickey OCaml book](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf), and trying to run the examples on pg. 157 of the book, 167 of the .pdf.  The problem arises with the expression

```
type ’a blob = < draw : unit; .. > as ’a
```

When I type that into my emacs buffer in tuareg-mode, and try to evaluate it with `C-c C-e`, I get the following error in the caml toplevel:

```
# type 'a blob = < draw : unit; .. > as ';;
Characters 39-41:
  type 'a blob = < draw : unit; .. > as ';;
                                         ^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Notice how the final `a` doesn't appear in command sent to the toplevel.  If I type the line into the toplevel directly, it works just fine:

```
# type 'a blob = < draw : unit; .. > as 'a;;
type 'a blob = 'a constraint 'a = < draw : unit; .. >
```

So my question is: Why doesn't this work, and how can I fix it?  Updating tuareg doesn't seem to be an option: I've tried to use tuareg version 2.0, but that won't even load properly.

**Update**:  This was fixed in the tuareg SVN trunk as of 12/8/12.  I don't think they've updated the release with the fix, but you can grab the trunk anonymously with

```
svn checkout svn://svn.forge.ocamlcore.org/svn/tuareg/trunk
```

bearing in mind the usual caveats about development vs. release versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug in Tuareg. For some reason he can't compute correctly the end of the phrase. To work around it, two possibilities:

- enclose your type in parentheses : `type 'a t = (<..> as 'a)` works
- send it to the toplevel manually: copy the line, paste it in the toplevel buffer, and add `;;` (phrase delimiter in the toplevel, optional in source code when it can be inferred).

Edit: it appears that the bug [has been reported upstream](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=770&group_id=43&atid=255). Hopefully they'll fix it sooner or later.